# UNIX - Find most elements in document

Tags: unix

I'm trying to figure out a way to take in a file where there is one word per line and output a log of the most frequently used words in the file and how often they occurred.

Namly, if I were given a file like this (far shorter than what I am looking at, but for clarity's sake...):

```
dog
dog
cat
bird
cat
horse
dog
```

I would get an output like:

```
dog - 3
cat - 2
bird - 1
horse - 1
```

Comment: there are a number of scripting languages available on most unix systems that could do this easily, which are you most familiar with? Python,shell scripting, PHP, Perl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
[cnicutar@fresh ~]$  sort < file | uniq -c | sort -rn
   3 dog
   2 cat
   1 horse
   1 bird
```

You can then tweak it to get dog-3 and so on.

Comment: "bird" is not sorted at the same place as OP ask

Comment: Is there a way to modify these commands such that only the top 5 words can be printed on the terminal?

Comment: @ShawnTaylor You can have another pipe to `head`. Try doing `head -n5`.

Answer (score 2):

using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) & [sort](/questions/tagged/sort) :

```
$ awk '{arr[$1]++}END{for(a in arr){print a" - "arr[a]}}' file.txt | sort -nrk3
```

A full [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) version :

```
awk '{
    arr[$1]++
}
END{
    for (i in arr) tmpidx[sprintf("%12s", arr[i]),i] = i
    num = asorti(tmpidx)
    j = 0
    for (i=num; i>=1; i--) {
        split(tmpidx[i], tmp, SUBSEP)
        indices[++j] = tmp[2]
    }
    for (i=1; i<=num; i++) print indices[i], arr[indices[i]]
}' file.txt
```

**OUTPUTs**

```
dog - 3
cat - 2
horse - 1
bird - 1
```

Another way using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) (exact output like you asked):

```
perl -lne '
    END{
        print "$_ - $h{$_}" for reverse sort {$h{$a} cmp $h{$b}} keys %h
    }
    $h{$_}++
' file.txt
```

**OUTPUT**

```
dog - 3
cat - 2
bird - 1
horse - 1
```